# Unable to move or delete file with \r in the name

Tags: bash, rename

Somehow i have tar file called 'secret\r-.tar.gz'.
Note that it has `\r` in the name.

I tried following SSH command for moving but none of them are working:

```
mv secret\r-.tar.gz ../
mv secret\\r-.tar.gz ../
mv secret\\r-.tar.gz ../
mv "secret\r-.tar.gz" ../
```

All resulted with error:

> mv: cannot stat `secret\r-.tar.gz': No such file or directory

Can you guys point me to the right direction.

Comment: Try to use the bash completion by pressing TAB to complete the file name with correct escaping.

Comment: What is the output of `printf '<%q>\n' *.tar.gz`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the file is literally called `secret\r-.tar.gz`, `mv "secret\r-.tar.gz" ../` should have worked.

If the `\r` is really a carriage return, you need to have a literal carriage return (and not an escape):

```
mv $'secret\r-.tar.gz' ..
```

Comment: mv "secret\r-.tar.gz" ../ -> is not working. but mv $'secret\r-.tar.gz' does.

Comment: Or `mv secret\^M-.tar.gz ..`, where `^M` is produced by pressing Ctrl-V, Ctrl-M.

Comment: @manatwork, note that the backslash above is not necessary since the CR character is not special to the shell.

Comment: Of course, is not. Thank you, @StephaneChazelas.

Answer (score 1):

You can generally use globbing (`*` or `?`) to deal with hard-to-type characters in file names.  For example:

```
mv secret?-.tar.gz something-more-appropriate.tar.gz
```

You might want to use `echo` or `ls` first to be sure of what you're getting.